Cogsci.SE FAQs?
Are there cogsci.SE FAQs anywhere?  I notice a lot of new participants coming in and of course not knowing that we are a little different than other SEs--more interested in cited evidence, less interested in anecdote/unsupported assertion.  I poked about a bit, and I've found references to a CogSci FAQ,  but can't find the FAQ itself.  

The help section at the top? I think that used to be called FAQ.

My help drop-down says Back to Tour/Help Center/Meta.  Is the Help Center what was formerly known as FAQ?  As a side note, the "How to write a good answer" page doesn't seem to address cogsci.SE in particular, just general SE.

Yes, quite certain that used to be the FAQ.

Long, long ago in the before time, Stack Exchange sites had a /faq URI containing frequently asked questions. This URL still exists: https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/faq but now it redirects to the "Tour"
Moderators can edit some parts of the Tour, including the introductory text "Cognitive Sciences is a question and answer site for [...] every question about cognitive sciences.", the question under Ask questions, get answers, no distractions, and the Ask About/Don't Ask About under Get answers to practical, detailed questions.
Because that is somewhat limited, there is also the "Community Maintained FAQ" which is done by tagging questions faq. If you see a question that you think should be in the faq, then edit it and add the faq-proposed tag.
